# Catch error by implemented interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have two custom error classes that both implement a `sendTo` function like this:

```
interface ISendableError {
    sendTo(res: express.Response, ctx: express.Request): express.Response;
}

class APIError extends Error implements ISendableError {
    /* ... */
    sendTo(res: express.Response, ctx: express.Request): express.Response { /* ... */ }
}

class ValidationError extends Error implements ISendableError {
    /* ... */
    sendTo(res: express.Response, ctx: express.Request): express.Response { /* ... */ }
}
```

I wanted to do something like this:

```
try {
    /* ... */
} catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof ISendableError) {
        e.sendTo(res, req);
    } else {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

... but obviously this does not work as ISendableError isn't a class but an interface. Something like a Java-kind multiple catch clauses could've been great for this problem:

```
try {
    /* ... */
} catch (e: ISendableError) {
    e.sendTo(res, req);
} catch (e) {
    /* ... */
}
```

but unfortunately this doesn't exist in Typescript.

I tried type guards

```
const isSendableError = (error: Error): error is ISendableError => {
    return (error as ISendableError).sendTo !== undefined;
}
```

But it seem that it can't work `A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.`, tho it works if `error` is annoted as `any` (which seem kinda dirty and allows any class to freely implements `ISendableError` even if they're not `Error`s).

Also I could use an abstract `SendableError` class, I don't know what the pros and cons are for each solution, but I liked the idea of matching an error by its interface.

Comment: Can't you do `catch (e) { if (e instanceof APIError || e instanceof ValidationError) { ...} }`?

Comment: @KarolMajewski I could but it means that if I ever add a new type of error, it won't automatically be added to all the try/catch clauses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct to say one cannot run `instanceof` checks against interfaces. They can be run only against classes.

You can create a `SendableError` class and make `APIError` and `ValidationError` inherit from it. There are some gotchas to be aware of when extending built-in constructors such as `Error` — I described them in the comments.

```
class SendableError extends Error implements ISendableError {
  constructor(readonly message: string) {
    super(message);

    /**
     * Extending built-in classes is a dangerous game in TypeScript.
     * When targeting ES5 and lower, prototype chains needs to be manually switched.
     *
     * @see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-wiki/blob/master/Breaking-Changes.md#extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-may-no-longer-work
     */
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, SendableError.prototype);

    /**
     * Maintains proper stack trace for where our error was thrown (only available on V8)
     *
     * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error
     */
    if ('captureStackTrace' in Error) {
      Error.captureStackTrace(this, SendableError);
    }
  }

  sendTo(res: express.Response, ctx: express.Request): express.Response { /* ... */ }
}
```

We could have made `SendableError` an abstract class, if that's what it is in your use case.

Now, the errors can extend `SendableError`.

```
class APIError extends SendableError {
  /* ... */
  sendTo(res: express.Response, ctx: express.Request): express.Response { /* ... */ }
}

class ValidationError extends SendableError {
  /* ... */
  sendTo(res: express.Response, ctx: express.Request): express.Response { /* ... */ }
}
```

And the try-catch block works.

```
try {
  /* ... */
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof SendableError) {
      e.sendTo(res, req);
  } else {
      /* ... */
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't knew extending from Error was that hard, thanks for the help! I think I'll go with the abstract class